# How can I recover a commit to an unnamed branch in Git?

Tags: git, branch

I did some changes and then did a commit. Then I realized that I am on an unnamed branch. So I checked out another branch (with a name). Now I want to recover the commit that I did to the unnamed branch or switch back to the unnamed branch so that I can put a name on it.

Is my commit lost forever?

Is there a way to see a list of all commits to all the branches and unnamed branches?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can inspect `git reflog` to see what your HEAD was pointing at previously. When you find the commit id, you can check it out via `git checkout <commit-id>`. Once you are on that commit, you can create a branch to point to it via `git checkout -b <branch-name>`.

Comment: Note that this is handy when you're using gitflow to merge a feature and you forget to run it with `-k` so that your branch is kept after merging...if you forget it, it's still there, just you have to look for it with `reflog` or `gitk --all` and then you can use the method above to give it a name locally.